# Huashan Cliffside Path: Accessible for tourists?

Tags: china, extreme-tourism, mountains

Today I saw some very nice pictures of the Huashan Cliffside Path in China:

[image]

Now I'm asking myself if this path is accessible for tourists? This means, if I have mountaineering experience can I walk there. What equipment do I need? Where can I get further information about the path?

Comment: This video does a pretty good job of most of your questions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsGC0lZ-5g8

Comment: I suspect it's designed for people lighter than me. (I'm not fat, but I am 6'4"!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you can still walk them as suicidal tourists:

> Its altitude is 1614m above sea level. Many trekkers and tourists have
>   died while walking down this trail. Local authorities have finally
>   woken up to the increasing number of tourists and added safety
>   measures like a chain, railings and deeper pathways. But these are
>   hardly any insurance against the risks of falling to one's death.
>   http://www.littleabout.com/Odd/3-trails-walking-kill/98881/

Also, I wouldn't trust those wooden planks with my life. They look very worn out and fragile like they would come off or break any time and are probably ...

(•_•)

( •_•)>⌐■-■

made in china.

(⌐■_■)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can!  I've been wanting to do this one for a long time but haven't been in the Xi'an area since I found out about it!

Hua Shan is about 80 miles from Xi'an in Shaanxi province.  There is a regular bus from Xi'an, or you can take a taxi although that will obviously cost more.

From all of the accounts I've read, as long as you're not afraid of heights, and as long as you've done at least a little of "semi-extreme" hiking then you'll have no problems completing the climb.

Mind you, if you'd prefer not to do the climb then you can always just take the cable car to the top!